# How to start Puma/Rails/Nginx on Debian after boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma

Ok, I'm deploying my Rails App using Capistrano. I'm also using Puma. I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) to get it to work, although I'm using Debian rather then Ubuntu.

Everything works fine and I can deploy my app without issues. However if my server crashes or the server restarts, the App doesn't restart itself and the only way I got it to restart was deploying it again with the following command `cap production deploy` from within my App in my local machine, which we all can agree that's not ideal.

There's loads of information on the web on how to deploy a Rails App with Passenger, which I'd rather avoid to use due to lack of resources on the server part. I've also found this [tutorial](https://technpol.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/configuring-puma-init-d-scripts-and-pumactl-on-debian-with-rvm/) which seems to be a bit outdated.

Can someone please point me to an updated tutorial or give some directions on how I could get my App to start/restart who the server?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

As per @mudasobwa's comments, I'm detailing the steps I've taken after reading this [page](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/init.d):

I have copied the contents of https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/tools/jungle/init.d/puma into `/etc/init.d/puma` made it executable. I've also copied the contents of https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/tools/jungle/init.d/run-puma into `/usr/local/bin/run-puma` also made it executable.

Lastly I've created a puma.conf file in `/etc`.

After that I've created the following directory: `/path/to/app/tmp/puma` and added these two files: `pid` and `state`. Note that I've also added the aforementioned folders into Capistrano's shared links structure.

After the above I've restarted my server and the App did not start as I expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle :: **TL;DR:** you need to provide an `upstart` script that takes care about daemons lifecircle on debian-like systems.

Comment: I've followed the steps but unfortunately that didn't work...

Comment: That perfectly works for people, so until you have more details provided we are unable to help further, unfortunately.

Comment: I've detailed the steps I've taken. Could you please let me know what am I missing? I'm not sure where I should add the app's minimal config...

Comment: OK. Does `sudo service puma start` start puma?

Comment: No it does not (I don't get the error from Debian though). I guess the problem is the missing configuration that the page mentions. Where should add that configuration?

Comment: Now you should probably ask for “starting puma server _as service_ on debian host” or like, I am not familiar with puma internals and unfortunately I am not able to guide you further.